# How can I set the id of an element, which is created by ngFor?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have created some elements:

```
<span *ngFor="let versuch of versuche">
  <div id="titleId[versuch]"><br></div>
</span>
```

`titleId` is a list of strings, where my element-ids are stored).

But if I try to get access to the elements, with `document.getElementById('__title__5')`, the element is not found (__title__5 is one of the element id's).

So do you know a way to set the id's per code?

Comment: In Angular you can simply use square brackets like so: `<div [id]="titleId[versuch]">`

Comment: The "Angular way" is use ViewChildren, see https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren#viewchildren. In general you should'nt need use document.getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [id] instead of id as in the example below:

```
<span *ngFor="let versuch of versuche">
    <div [id]="titleId[versuch]"><br></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ngAttr` **for binding to arbitrary attributes AngularJS**

For example, considering this template

```
<span *ngFor="let versuch of versuche">
  <div ng-attr-id="{{ 'titleId-' + versuch  }}"><br></div>
</span>
```

Doc - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes

**Angular**

```
 <li *ngFor="item of items" #elem [attr.id]="item.id">
        {{ item.name}} ID: {{elem.id}}
 </li>
```

Comment: NOT use as name of variable `#item`, the `#` is only to template reference variable (as you're using in `#elem`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` from the `*ngFor`. Try the following

**Option 1 - `titleId` is an array of strings**

```
<span *ngFor="let versuch of versuche; let i=index">
  <div attr.id="{{titleId[i]}}"><br></div>
</span>
```

**Option 2 - `titleId` not used**

If you need to have corresponding id's based on the index of the `versuche` variable, you can skip the variable `titleId` and do it directly in the template.

```
<span *ngFor="let versuch of versuche; let i=index">
  <div [attr.id]="'__title__' + i">{{versuch}}<br></div>
</span>
```

**Option 3 - `titleId` is an object**

If the `titleId` is an object with keys corresponding to each `versuche`, then the following should work

component

```js
  versuche = [ 'versuche_1', 'versuche_2', 'versuche_3' ];
  titleIdObj = {
    'versuche_1': '__title__1',
    'versuche_2': '__title__2',
    'versuche_3': '__title__3',
  }
```

template

```
<span *ngFor="let versuch of versuche">
  <div attr.id="{{titleIdObj[versuch]}}">{{versuch}}<br></div>
</span>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ayuxqc)